# Will my dog’s leg be healed if he has damaged his leg?

Tags: dogs, health

**Context**

Few days ago, when it was Halloween event, I used to play with my sister’s cool balloon and when the dog saw it, he jumped and barked at the ballon( I didn’t know why, but I never thought of what consequences he’ll have). So I put on my sister’s desk and at night he tried to jump to the balloon and when he jumped, something wrong has happened. An accident. I felt very bad for him.

He has also had a crotch neck due to the fact that, a girl unintentionally when she raised him in her arms, he accidentally escaped and fell, and that caused him to have a crotched neck.

And if he will never heal up, I would feel the most miserable being because I didn’t know how to take care of him. And he has become my responsibility until the death comes upon him( in a natural way).

**Question:** Can someone please tell me if, my dog will be healed? Because, I’m very worried about him. I do not want to feel as if I have wretched the poor dog’s life. Because, simply it is not in my intention.

**NOTE:** If I have asked in a wrong site, can you please immigrate how to the right site?

Comment: Sprain should heal.  Fractured bone not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you want to use that as an answer.

A sprain should heal.  If the dog is still limping in a week you should see a vet.

A torn legitimate will not heal and surgery is not cheap.

A fractured bone will not heal correctly without a cast.  It is *typically* obvious on inspection.

Lightly squeeze the leg section by section and look for pain.  Last compress the hips lightly.

I am not a vet but I did ski patrol did a lot of injuries.

Comment: Hopefully my dog will be 100% healed

Comment: And I hope it is not a bone fracture.